# How to fix the Biber/Biblatex incompatibility?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I did read the various answers to similar questions but they did not help.

I am on Ubuntu 20.40.2, and I use TexStudio for editing/compiling my LaTeX documents.

I recently uninstalled TexLive and reinstalled it in my `user` directory (I installed the `texlive-full` (the 2021 version) in accordance with the instructions found [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)). When I tried compiling a beamer presentation, I got the following error message:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'presentation.blg'
INFO - Reading 'presentation.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.7.
This means that your biber (2.16) and biblatex (3.10) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

However, when I tried to update my packages in `tlmgr`, I found that biblatex is actually ver 3.16 (and not 3.10).
[image: A screenshot from my tlmgr1]

I do not know how to begin diagnosing the problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two latex installations? You mentioned you installed texlive into your user directory. How precisely did you add texlive to your PATH? And how exactly did you start texstudio? From a menu, double clicking a file? Additionally what does `which biber` and `locate biber` say?

Comment: @daleif I am quite sure that I have only one installation. Is there any way to check, regardless? I added texlive to PATH by adding a file texlive.sh to `/etc/profile.d/`, where I added the required lines in accordance with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554214/128480) answer (the PATH, MANPATH and INFOPATH were provided at the end of the installation). I started texstudio by double-clicking a file. `which biber` returns `/home/VBtheHun/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/biber`, and `locate biber` says nothing.

Comment: Try running `sudo updatedb` to load the database for locate

Comment: And what version is biber? `biber -version` or similar. Was the file from before you installed tl21? Then try deleting the old generated files

Comment: I ran `sudo updatedb` and then `locate biber`. I got many lines of output. The first line was `/home/VBtheHun/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/biber` with a whole host of others (mostly PDFs) in `/home/VBtheHun/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/examples/...` and a few others as well. All in `/home/VBtheHun/texlive/2021/`, though. `biber --version` returns `2.16`.

Comment: Did you delete the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` files before you compiled your presentation? Does the error persist if you try to run a simple document in a new, empty folder? What output does `kpsewhich -all biblatex.sty` produce? Open the `biblatex.sty` indicated by the first line of the `kpsewhich` output and check its version number. Does it say 3.10 or 3.16?

Comment: @moewe yes I deleted all files. In fact, I copied just the .tex and .bib file to a new folder and compiled it from there, still the same results. `kpsewhich -all biblatex.sty` returned `/home/VBtheHun/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty' and `/home/VBtheHun/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty`. The first one says version 3.10 and the second one says 3.16. Hmm, you might be onto something.

Comment: @moewe renaming the first texmf file worked! I had previously installed texlive-basic and had installed a few packages later, and those packages ended up in my `user` directory. They managed to slip through even [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95502/128480) method of uninstalling Texlive completely (now the solution seems obvious). Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your TeX distribution's package manager (`tlmgr` or MikTeX Console) reports matching versions of `biblatex` and Biber and you still get a version mismatch after deleting the temporary `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` files, chances are, there are several competing versions of Biber or `biblatex` on your machine.

To **find all competing versions of Biber on your machine**, type

```
which -a biber
```

on Unixoid systems and

```
where biber
```

on Windows.

This should return all paths to Biber versions found on your machine. If there are several different Bibers in different paths, check if one of them is an remnant of an old installation. Also compare the output to the result of `which -a pdflatex`/`where pdflatex`.

To **find all competing versions of `biblatex` on your machine**, type

```
kpsewhich -all biblatex.sty
```

Ideally the path returned by `kpsewhich` for `biblatex.sty` should be compatible with the path for Biber: they should live in the same subtree, e.g. `/home/VBtheHun/texlive/2021/` or `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX`.

---

As discussed in the comments, it turned out that there was a local installation of an outdated version of `biblatex` that masked the system installed version, which matched the Biber version.

`kpsewhich -all biblatex.sty` returned

```
/home/VBtheHun/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
/home/VBtheHun/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
```

where the first file was a local installation of `biblatex` v3.10 and the second the system-controlled installation of the current v3.16.

Deleting the local installation of `biblatex` completely, i.e. removing

```
/home/VBtheHun/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex
```

resolves the problem.

It is worth checking out which other packages hang around in

```
/home/VBtheHun/texmf
```

and mask system-wide installed more recent versions of the same package.